# How to automatically Import data from MS excel CELLS to table cells?

Tags: data-merge, import, microsoft-excel

i have a huge MS excel file with 120 columns and 20 rows.
I want to import all the data from excel cells into table cells in CorelDraw (**or may be other graphic design software**).

Here there are two screenshots for what i want to do. For a small table manual typing is good but I want to implement the same thing on 120 
columns*20 rows table in CorelDraw. How do I automate this?

**Does Adobe Photoshop or other graphic software have such built-in functionality, for importing the excel data into table cells?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi user38436 I took the liberty of editing your question to make it more clear. I think the word you're looking for is _data merge_, quite a few softwares have it built-in (Indesign, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import excel file into InDesing with no problem. You can also link the source file so InDesign will be "aware" of changes made to excel file.

Placing (or pasting) tables into Illustrator or Photoshop make them, respectively, vector or rasterized objects.
Bear in mind that CorelDraw, Illustrator and Photoshop are software to create graphic and not to handle and use long text and tables.